# WCF callback with multiple clients

Tags: wcf, callback

Can I have two different clients listening to the same WCF callback and have them both receive the same data without having to do the processing twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really - at least not directly. What you're describing sounds a lot like the publish/subscribe pattern. A WCF service basically services one client and one client only, at any given time.

There are ways to do this in WCF 3.5 and better ones in WCF 4.0 - with or without Windows Azure's .NET Services. There are also other tools and support for the publish/subscribe pattern.

Check out things like:

- [WCF Implementation of the Publish/Subscribe model](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22796/WCF-Implementation-of-the-Publisher-Subscriber-Mod)
- [Building a Pub/Sub Message Bus with WCF and MSMQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tomholl/building-a-pubsub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq)
- [NServiceBus](https://web.archive.org/web/20160420234146/http://docs.particular.net:80/nservicebus/architecture/nservicebus-and-wcf)

If you Google or Bing for "WCF Publish Subscribe", you'll get a lot more hits - but those three should really get you started, I think.

Comment: what if each client issues a request asking to be notified of the same event. Then, when the event occurs, the OP basically wants to do what .NET does when firing an event: call back each client with the event notification.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the links @marc_s posted, you can also check out Juval Lowy's Publish/Subscribe Framework, which is shown graphically below.

[image: Publish-Subscribe Framework]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/cc163537.fig07(en-us).gif))</sub>
.

This framework is described in detail in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues).  And you can download the [framework's source code](http://www.idesign.net/Downloads#Operations) for free at Lowy's website, [IDesign.net](http://www.idesign.net).

Using the Pub/Sub Service allows the Publisher to publish the event ***once*** to a well-known endpoint.  The Pub/Sub Service then takes care of publishing the notification to the subscribed clients.